# My background image got distorted if my app is run on small screen or when emulator at run time is set to landscape mode

Tags: android

My background image got distorted if my app is run on small screen or when emulator at run time is set to landscape mode.

I have already tried by placing my images in hdpi mdpi and ldpi folders.

Comment: have you tried setting hdpi/mdpi/ldpi-land folders?

Comment: @Amad actually i dont know the dimensions of images needed for landscape mode so i didnt use land-folders, but i use hdpi with 480*800 pixels. Quality of my is improved but not upto that level which i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set different image sizes, cannot use the same image in all the folders. For more info, go through this link - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: hey thanx yaar but the thing is still not understand that what to do know?
Because I am not using any repeating Images and i have tried using these images by putting in hdpi, ldpi & mdpi . Can you please tell me this by any example.

Comment: What is repeating images? you need to put the same set of images with the same names in all the folders with respective sizes. For landscape mode add folder mdpi-land and add the image that has proper dimensions, otherwise android will try to stretch ur image and will indeed distort it

Comment: ok i will ttry for it definitely thanx for your instant replies,
Also please tell me that wat do u mean by proper dimension do i need to change dimensions of each image if i am using it in mdpi-land

Comment: on making a new folder mdpi-land(with images) in resources(res) folder it is showing error...

Comment: 36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density

Comment: res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   //for medium-density screens
res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png   //for high-density screens

Comment: res/drawable-nodpi/icon.png if u dont want any scaling

Comment: 240*320,320*480 and 480*800 these are in pixels and that u above mentioned are in which units and are these same as I mentioned in this post. also please tell me image size for landscape mode i dont find any effective answer for it so that image will not distorted, if i run my program in any android device or emulator